# If-statement GetType() c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF,

`if (number = int) {//; bla bla bla...}` 
OR

`if (number = double) {//; bla bla bla...}`

How to code this if-statement: `if (numerator.GetType==int){...}` ?

The main trouble is in this: I read nominator and denominator from textbox, with var dr1 = textBox1.Text.Split('/');   ! split, but how i can gettype from string ???

Comment: Are you looking for `if(numerator.GetType() == typeof(int))`? If not, please add to your question because as it is it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This looks like a problem where either function overloads or generics might be better than boxed numbers.

Comment: The main trouble is in this: I read nominator and denominator from textbox, with var dr1 = textBox1.Text.Split('/');   ! split, but how i can gettype from string ???

Comment: If you're reading a number as a string, do you care if it's an integer? Why not just always assume it's a `double`?

Comment: it's my lab) i have to read from textbox, and if type in textbox is int do method1, else do another method

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if (numerator is int) { ... }
```

or

```
if (numerator.GetType() == typeof(int)) {...}
```

The former is usually better.

EDIT:
Нou say the problem is parsing numbers from string representation. I'm afraid, the best approach here is to call `type.TryParse` and check if given string can be parsed as a number of given type.

E.g.

```
var tokens = line.Split('/');
double dArg1,dArg2; int iArg1, iArg2;
if (int.TryParse(tokens[0], out iArg1) 
    && int.TryParse(tokens[1], out iArg2)){
    return iArg1/iArg2;
} else if (double.TryParse(tokens[0], out dArg1) 
           && double.TryParse(tokens[1], out dArg2)){
    return dArg1/dArg2;
} else { /* handle error */ }
```

Note that all `int`s can be parsed as `double`s, so you need to try to parse token as `int` before trying to parse it as `double.

Comment: The main trouble is in this: I read nominator and denominator from textbox, with var dr1 = textBox1.Text.Split('/');   ! split, but how i can gettype from string ???

Answer (score 5):

```
if (numerator.GetType() == typeof(int))
{
    ...
}
```

[typeof (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The main trouble is in this: I read nominator and denominator from textbox, with var dr1 = textBox1.Text.Split('/');   ! split, but how i can gettype from string ???

Comment: @user707895, post another question with explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can use the typeof-operator:

```
if(typeof(int) == numerator.GetType())
{
    //put code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try the is/as operator:

```
if (numerator is int) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**is** operator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

```
if(number is int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
if ( value is int ) { }
```

You may also want to take a look at [Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (numerator.GetType() == typeof(int))
{
   // it's an int

}

else if (numerator.GetType() == typeof(double))
{
   // it's a double
}
```

Not sure why you'd want to do that though...

Comment: The main trouble is in this: I read nominator and denominator from textbox, with var dr1 = textBox1.Text.Split('/');   ! split, but how i can gettype from string ???

Comment: Why don't you convert everything to double? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx) That will work either if the user writes "1" or "1.0".

Answer (score 0):

C# 7

```
if (number is int myint) {//; do something with myint} OR

if (number is double mydouble) {//; do something with mydouble}
```

Each case is true if the type matches.  The cast value will be placed in the variable.